# Finding out when a line has been modified in a H2 database table

Tags: java, database, line, h2, last-modified

Let's imagine I have two processes A and B performing transactions on a H2 database table T.

Process A performs CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on T.

Process B wants to know when line L in T has been last modified (i.e., B provides a `System.currentTimeMillis()` value for example).

One could create a column in T registering the last modification moment for each line, but I was wondering whether H2 was already holding this information somewhere and whether it can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my knowledge there is no such feature in H2 (and probably not in any RDBMS). The reason is simple - extra 4 or 8 bytes per each record might have a huge impact on overall database size, especially with small records. Also there will be a slight performance impact.

But it is relatively simple to implement this feature by using extra column and on update trigger. Also some databases might simplify it even further, like MySQL:

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Also please distinguish between database server clock, process A clock and process B clock. In real world they most likely won't be the same.

Comment: I guess the next step for me is to find out whether this can be automated. Thanks.

Comment: There are some trigger examples in `src/test/org/h2/samples`.

Answer (score 1):

The database only store what you setup.

So you must set the table to store the modification time, and one really easy way to do it is by creating a "Computed Column" with the value of `now()`, A computed column is evalueated each time that the record is modified.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR, LAST_MOD TIMESTAMP AS NOW());
```

FYI: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#computed_columns